# Store & display user input in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to display and print a word from the user and store it into my array which is called

```
char word[20]
```

But I am having trouble. I know we use a "for loop" to scan it into the array but I keep going in circles and I believe the problem is with the `i < 20`. 
I researched this and found that the answers to this are extremely experienced and I need a really basic way of doing it without the extra stuff. So all I want is to get word from the user, store it and print it onto the screen.

Can someone help without experienced code?

Code in C

```
char getWord(char word[]);
int main()
{   
    char word[20];  
    getWord(word);

    return 0;
}

char getWord(char word[])
{ 
    int i;
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    { 
        scanf(" %c", &word[i]);
    }

    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you want is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word[20];
    scanf("%s", word);    // Read and store
    printf("%s\n", word);    // Print
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this the other way instead of using a for loop?

Comment: scanf with %s scans a string (without any whitespace or new line) to a char array. so you need not to scan each character using for loop. Yeah, this is perfect way instead of for loop.

Comment: But wait, there's more. You also get a buffer overflow, *absolutely free*!

Comment: Actually, you want to protect from buffer overrun with `scanf("%20s", word)`

Comment: You should always ***validate*** the return of `scanf`, e.g. `if (scanf ("%19s", word) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`. Otherwise you can have no confidence `printf("%s\n", word);` won't invoke *Undefined Behavior*. (@wallyk -- it's `"%19s"` instead of `"%20s"` -- that can exceed the array bounds by `1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets and puts to read and write a string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 20

int main()
{
    int ar[MAX], i, count;
    fgets(ar, MAX, stdin);  //it will accept whitespaces as well
    puts(ar);            //displaying entered string
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

if you want to read via characters, ending character should be set to null character for it to be string.

```
char getWord(char word[]);
int main() 
{
    char word[20]
    getWord(word);

    printf("%s\n", word);
    return 0;
}

char getWord(char word[]) 
{
    int i;
    char c;
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if ( c == '\n' )
            break;
        word[i]=c;
    }

    word[i]='\0';
    return word;
}
```